# How to get the first word before a dash in Swift?

Tags: swift, string

I would like to get the first year of this string. The one before the dash `-`: "2007-2016"

How can I achieve this within Swift 3?

I did some research and there is an function called `substring` or `index` but doesn't know which one I should use.

What I want to achieve is a sort function that will sort on year. So I think the best way to do this is using the first year (from year). There are also objects that only contains one year...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `index(of:)` and `substring(to:)`.

Following your comment, I've also added an example to get the second year.

```
let str = "2007-2016"

if let idx = str.characters.index(of: "-") {
    let year1 = str.substring(to: idx)
    print(year1)
    let year2 = str.substring(from: str.index(after: idx))
    print(year2)
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get the value after the dash?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer (and changed the "index" variable name to "idx" to avoid confusing it with the `index` we're using on the string for extracting "year2").

Answer (score 0):

Two (other) solutions:

```
let string = "2007-2016"

let year1 = string.components(separatedBy: "-").first!

let year2 : String
if let range = string.range(of: "-") {
    year2 = string.substring(to: range.lowerBound)
} else {
    year2 = string
}
```

If there is no dash in the string the result is the whole string.